# need to get auto increment where datatype in database is "Int"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I would like to know how to get an auto increment for the `MRF No`. when submitting data to the database. Like the starting MRF no. is `2018001` and next one will be `2018002`.

**Code:**

```
private void getMRF_No()
    {
        string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        int mrf = 0;
        string mrfNo = "";
        database db = new database();
        string conn = db.MRF();
        SqlConnection connUser = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = connUser.CreateCommand();
        SqlDataReader sdr = null;

        string query = "SELECT TOP 1 MRF_NO FROM MRF_DETAILS ORDER BY MRF_NO DESC";

        connUser.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            mrfNo = sdr.GetString(0);
        }

        if (mrfNo == "")
        {

            mrfNo = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + 10001;
        }
        mrf += 1;
        txtMRFNo.Text = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + mrfNo;

        connUser.Close();

    }
```

It seems I am getting an error that says "The conversion of the `nvarchar` value '`2018201810001`' overflowed an int column. I would like to know any way to improve this to get the code to work.

Thank you!

Comment: you may need to change your (i assume slq server?) column data type that holds the id to be of type `bigint` (`long` in .net)

Comment: what after `20181009`? its `201810010` or `20181021` or `?`

Comment: First you do `mrfNo = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + 10001` and then `txtMRFNo.Text = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + mrfNo;` -- which means that you add the year *twice*

Comment: I assume `MRF_NO` is an int column? Why are you reading and manipulating it as string in your code (`mrfNo`)? And you are not really using `mrf`, did you mean that?

Comment: If your current year `2019` and your query returns `2018...` then what you think how your auto increment works?

Answer (score 1):

The range of an `int` data type is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

Change your column data type that holds the ID to be of type `bigint`

The range of a `bigint` data type is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

(bigint is the same as a `long` type in .net)

Comment: tbh i would like to send it as 20181001 like my question said. the thing is when i change the data type of MRF_No in the database, it ends up as "2018201810001" upon success. then the next one will be "20182018201810001". I was hoping it would be 20181001 and then 20181002 later on

Comment: look like you are adding it or something.  if you want my advice use a normal Pk identity column of type int.  then in another column you have you 'descriptive' ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use unsignedInt datatype.

```
int range:            -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 
unsignedInt range:     0 to 4,294,967,295 
long/bigint range:    -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Your value '2018201810001' is exceeding max int value 2,147,483,647 and so throws error

So change datatype of 'mrf' from 'int' to uint'. If you think other column values can exceed int range, then change their datatype also.

If 'uint' is still to small, use 'long/bigint' instead.

Comment: _txtMRFNo.Text = Convert.ToString(year) + "" + mrfNo;_
You're adding the year as a string a second time in your code.
You're adding it twice I think that's your issue here.

Comment: bad advice on the decimal usage- i hope that was a typo

Comment: @JohnB Yes you are right. 'ulong' would've been the better option.

Comment: hmm, we need to talk in the language or terminology of the db - which i assume is sql server.  so the answer should be `bigint`

Comment: how do i change it so it can show 20181001 and then the next is 20181002 then??

Comment: @allos If I'd be you I wouldn't use a string/nvarchar for this. Use long/bigint and instead of adding `2018` to your _string_ add `20180000` to your _long_.

Comment: @godfather so i will change the datatype in the sql then?

Comment: @allos Yeah change the datatype in sql from `nvarchar` to `bigint`. In your code change your type from `int` to `long`. Then add _2018_ as _20180000_.

Comment: I am not sure you really need a bigint datatype as apparently your calculation needs fixing: it keeps adding the year in front, which seems to be a mistake

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Yeah for some reason he is adding the year twice. Let's say he wants to do such thing. It won't work unless you use a larger datatype.

Comment: @godfather If the OP keeps adding the year, even a bigint will fail after a few updates

Comment: @HansKeﬆing We need clarification from allos about what he's trying to do.

Comment: What i am looking for is to show the the MRF No., which is something like 20181001 to be shown in the textbox and upon submitting it will be stored in the data, then the next time the web page loads, the MRF_No will be 20181001 before submitting. Hope this makes it clearer. :D Sorry am still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I would like to simplify your code, you do not have to change the data type in the database, if you think that MRF_No will never exceed int range.

```
private void getMRF_No()
{
     string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    //you can add number within SQL, it is not recommend to use IsNull, you can remove 
    //IsNUll(MRF_NO,0) and just use MRF_NO, if you think MRF_NO will never be NULL
    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 IsNUll(MRF_NO,0) +1 [MRF_NO] FROM MRF_DETAILS ORDER BY MRF_NO DESC"; 


    var dt = new DataTable();
    using(var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, new SqlConnection(conn)))
    {
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }

    var mrfNo= (dt.Rows.Count > 0) ? Int64.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) : 1; 

    //year is already string,do not have to convert and ToString method of Int can format 
    // your number
    txtMRFNo.Text = year + mrfNo.ToString("000");
}
```